# File Reading Error in document directory iOS

Tags: ios, filereader

I am getting this error while reading the file from document directory.The content in the file is encrypted string. I am reading the file content in NSData. On going further I am doing decryption. But since it is not able to read any content, unable to display the decrypted content.

My code is:

```
    //reading the file content
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"encryp.txt"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
   data1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePath];
}
    else
{
    NSLog(@"File not exits");
}
```

//decryption of file content

```
    NSError *error1;

NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

strKey =[defaults valueForKey:@"hashOfPassword"];

NSData *decryptedData1 = [RNDecryptor decryptData:data1 withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:strKey error:&error1];

NSLog(@"Decrypted Data is: %@", decryptedData1);

NSString* decryptedStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"dercrypted string is:%@", decryptedStr1);
```

By adding the breakpoint I got this error

```
    (NSError *) error1 = 0x00000001 domain: <read memory from 0xd failed (0 of 4 bytes read)> - code: <read memory from 0x9 failed (0 of 4 bytes read)>
```

And I am not getting this. Please Help!!

Comment: Note: Do not save the key in `NSUserDefaults`, that is very insecure, use the Keychain, it is secure.

Comment: Check the actual file and it's contents either in the simulator with the finder or terminal, on the device you can access the file with Xcode. Make sure it exists and has the correct content. Best guess is that it did not get saved.